# How PostgreSQL WHERE clause work in this query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can someone explain how this **WHERE** clause work in this query?

```sql
    SELECT * FROM "User" AS U
    WHERE ((U."ID", U."age") > (23820, 25));
```

As I understand Postgres returns users where the id is greater than 23820 and ignore the age column.

Comment: I recommend to just try out. I created an example here and created a second query which determines the identic output. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9ff1c6dbc9e69bd4bfca0b38f506f27e

Comment: Ahhh..... I get it. Thanks a lot @jonas-metzler.

Comment: @Bagrat thanks for asking such nice question. And thanks Jonas for the answer.

Comment: That's "tuple inequality". PostgreSQL is one of the few databases that implement it.

Comment: Thank you, @The Impaler. I prevented writing an answer instead of just a comment because I was just trying it out without being able to write a general summary. Maybe you could add it if you want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JonasMetzler is correct on the comment. Postgres apparently uses this set as something on the lines of:

```
Most left parameter uses the operator, all the others use equal
OR
 repeat until one parameter left (
     Remove most left parameter + 
     Most left parameter uses the operator, all the others use equal 
  )
```

```
(parameter_n, [parameter_n-1, ..., parameter_n-final]) <operator> (value_n, [value_n-1, ..., value_n-final])

equals to

(parameter_n = value_n AND parameter_n-1 = value_n-1 AND ... parameter_n-final <operator> value_n-final)
OR 
(parameter_n = value_n AND parameter_n-1 = value_n-1 AND ... parameter_n-final-1 <operator> value_n-final-1)
OR 
...
(parameter_n = value_n AND parameter_n-1 <operator> value_n-1)
OR 
(parameter_n <operator> value_n)
```

Comment: "...all the others use equal..." .. No. Tuples inequality works on all components of the tuple. If one component comparison results in equality it moves into the next one.